# Variance of Sample Mean using Expectations Operator

Tags: statistics, variance, means, sampling

I am trying to work out the derivation of the variance of the sample mean. It is clear to me how the normal proof using $\frac{1}{n^2}(n\sigma^2)$ works. However, I was trying to work out how to do the same proof using the good old $Var(X) = E[(X-E[X])^2]$ and couldn't quite work it out. There must be something fundamental I am missing. What I have worked out so far is this:

$$
Var(\overline{x}) = E\left[\left(\frac{\sum_i x_i}{n}-E\left[\frac{\sum_i x_i}{n}\right]\right)^2\right]\\ = 
E\left[\left(\frac{\sum_i x_i}{n}\right)^2-2*\frac{\sum_i x_i}{n}*E\left[\frac{\sum_i x_i}{n}\right]+E\left[\frac{\sum_i x_i}{n}\right]^2\right] \\
= E\left[\left(\frac{\sum_i x_i}{n}\right)^2\right]-E\left[\frac{\sum_i x_i}{n}\right]^2
$$

I think the latter term can be re-written as $\frac{1}{n}E[x]^2$, but I am struggling with the rest. How do I do this?

Comment: Hint: expand $(\sum x_i / n)^2$ into the sum of $n^2$ terms.

Comment: Use $Var(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2$. Let $Y=X^2$ and get $Var(Y)$